# Improve performance of insert?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I ran the Performance – Top Queries by Total IO (I am trying to improve this process).

The top #1 is this code:

```
DECLARE @LeadsVS3 AS TT_LEADSMERGE 

DECLARE @LastUpdateDate DATETIME 

SELECT @LastUpdateDate = MAX(updatedate) 
FROM [BUDatamartsource].[dbo].[salesforce_lead] 

INSERT INTO @LeadsVS3
    SELECT 
        Lead_id, 
        (more columns…)
        OrderID__c,
        City__c
    FROM
        [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Lead]
    WHERE
        UpdateDate > @LastUpdateDate
```

(the code is a piece of a larger SP)

[image]

[image]

This is in a job that runs every 15 minutes... Other than running the job less frequently is there any other improvement I could make?

Comment: what does the schema look like for the table type `TT_LEADSMERGE` ?

Comment: What is volume of data? Why you are using tablevariable?

Comment: Here SELECT/Scan is faster and INSERT is slow which means you have bottleneck of IO/memory... Since here target is table variable your storage will be In-Memory for certain extent after that it will be in your tempdb, How tempdb is configured? Does it has enough space?

Comment: Do you have an index on UpdateDate in [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Lead]? How long is it taking? notice that 97% is a relative cost

Comment: Can you publish the actual execution plan results...

Comment: Aside: Is there _any_ chance of duplicate `UpdateDate` values? Do you mind dropping some rows if that occurs?

Comment: Hard to tell from the snippet but...things I would check (that could slow things down): `UpdateDate` on the select not having an index, triggers on the `TT_LEADSMERGE` table doing things for every insert. Fragmentation of pages on `TT_LEADSMERGE` (tweak the fill-factor). How fast does each `select` part alone run?  are they long queries?

Answer (score 0):

Make a try with a local hash table like #LeadsVS3, it is faster than udtt in most cases

Also there is another trick you may do.

On those cases where you always get all 'recent' rows, you may get locked for 1 row, the latest, waiting to commit. You may sacrifice a small part e.g. 1 minute that is to ignore last minute records ( current datetime - 1 minute ). You get those to the next run and save yourself any transaction (or replication) lock waits.

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan that you posted appears to be the *estimated* execution plan. (the *actual* execution plan includes the *actual* number of rows).  Without the actual plan it's impossible to tell what's really going on.

The ***obvious improvement*** would be to add a covering nonclustered index on Lead.leadid that includes the other columns in your SELECT statement. Right now your scanning a the widest possible index (your clustered index) to retrieve a presumably small percentage of records. Turning that clustered scan into a non-clustered *seek* will be huge.

On that same note you could make that index a filtered index that's only includes records for dates greater than your last UpdateDate. Then setup a regular SQL Job that periodically rebuilds it to filter on a more current date.

**Other things you can do to increase insert performance:**

1. Drop any constraints and/or indexes before the insert then rebuild
   them after.
2. Use smaller data types